# Firebase + Google Games Services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-games, developer-console

While setting up Firebase and Google Game Services it is not possible to link the app in the Play Developer Console (games services). Firebase projects auto generate the relevant api keys etc. altering these breaks Firebase.

I also tried creating a game from an existing project in the api console but it could not find any.

Has anyone had this and overcome it before?

I have confirmed that the Firebase implementation works as well as the Games Services implementation when they are independent of each other.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. I created a new project using Firebase console. And when i'm creating the game in Google Play Console it creates a new project instead of choosing previously created project.

Comment: I did get around this, so Firebase auto generates the Google Api project. I think I removed the Android entry in OAuth 2.0 client IDs and then linked the app in games services. It was a very awkward process as Firebase, Games Services and the Api Console seem to be in some kind of battle with each other.

Comment: I followed the same process. And I successfully linked my app with Game Services. But now I can't add production keystore footprint for the Firebase project. Hope It won't be problematic.

Comment: I have no doubt it will be nothing less than problematic! I may sent Firebase a message and see what they have to say.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the account you're using on Play Developer Console is not an owner of the Project you defined in Firebase. Can you verify if the logged in user account in Play is added as an owner for the given project on: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin? You should then be able to import the project on the Play Developer Console.